# What is the best way to make a diagram from some query data?

Tags: android, histogram, diagram

i want to make a diagram from some values in database. so what is the way to make and show a 2D or 3D diagram,Histogram or Line graph to user.

Comment: The best way is to write the code.

Comment: is there any api or class to do this ??? or some example to make diagraam with java ??

Comment: Yes, there should be such api... But such questions are off-topic for SO as SO is not human search engine. Use Internet search engine.

Comment: i am sorry but i searched about this and found not usefull examples.

Comment: i found somthing now because before i searched with bing and now with google i found this
http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/how-to-create-a-simple-graph

Comment: Searching with bing is wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend MPAndroidChart. It is a fast and stable chart library which provides a lot of customization settings.

In my current project I discarded the graphview-library and moved to MPAndroidChart due to performance issues with graphview.